# Android no rule to make target

Tags: android, c++

In my android project in eclipse juno no error is shown in any source file but the project is red marked and when clean command is conduct the the error is shown  "make: *** No rule to make target `clean'.  Stop."  In the problem log it is shown a type "c/c++ problem". Please give me any idea about the problem.

Comment: use MakeFile instead makefile..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The make command by default looks for `makefile`, `Makefile`, and `GNUMakefile` as the input file, don't use any extensions. Hope this helps.. :)